postgis, actualizar columna geom de una tabla a otra con diferentes campos y un campo en comun
Tengo una tabla en PostGIS con un campo de geometria y un campo idauto y quiero actualizar otra tabla que comparte el campo idauto y tiene el campo geom a NULL.
Quiero copiar las geometrias de la tabla 1 a la tabla 2, cada geometria deberia ir a su registro con el mismo idauto.
He probado varias soluciones de otra consultas pero no me actualiza nada, el campo geom sigue a NULL.
Esta es la tabla "LIMITES_PARC_PROY" de la que quiero coger la geometria.

y esta sería la tabla "PARCELAS" a la que quiero pegar las geometrias de la otra tabla:


he probado esta query, me dice que ha actualizado los registro pero no veo las geometrias copiadas a sus respetivos registros.
UPDATE public."PARCELAS"
SET geom = (
    SELECT geom
    FROM public."LIMITES_PARC_PROY"
    WHERE public."LIMITES_PARC_PROY".idauto = public."PARCELAS".idauto
)
WHERE idauto IN (
    SELECT idauto
    FROM public."LIMITES_PARC_PROY"
);


Me salta la duda, en porque hay una subconsulta, en vez de solamente leer los datos de la otra tabla y copiarlos a la nueva tabla.
En tu caso, probaría algo más simple:
UPDATE public."PARCELAS" AS p --tabla a actualizar
SET p.geom = l.geom --valor a actualizar
FROM public."LIMITES_PARC_PROY" AS l --tabla de donde obtenermos los valores
WHERE p.idauto = l.idauto; --y que tengan la misma id

Vale aclarar que estoy asumiendo que la columna geom, es del mismo tipo que la original cierto ?

Sí, la columna geom es del mismo tipo. Voy a probar esta query.

Funciona perfecto y mucho mas sencillo.
